# While statement and def function

Tags: python

I'm learning the def function and wrote this code:

```
def thirdpower(number):
    n=number**3
    print "%d to the 3rd power is %d" % (number,n)
thirdpower(input("Enter a number"))
```

But now, I want to add in a conditional statement (perhaps using the while statement) so that if a user leaves the input blank, it will print out an error, and will re-ask the user.

So far, I can't figure it out:

```
def thirdpower(number):
        n=number**3
while True:
    if len(thirdpower())==0:
        print "%d to the 3rd power is %d" % (number,n)
        thirdpower(input("Enter a number"))
    break
else:
    print "you entered a blank, please try again."
```

Any input is apreciated!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python functions are recursive, use this functionnality :

```
def thirdpower():
    try:
        number = int(raw_input("Enter a number : "))
        n=number**3
        print "%d to the 3rd power is %d" % (number,n)
    except ValueError:
        print "You must enter an integer, please try again."
        thirdpower()

thirdpower()
```

The try: ... except:... blocks is used to determine if the value is an integer or not.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I know exactly what you are up to, but this might help:

```
def thirdpower(n):
    return n**3
number = None
while not number:
    try:
        number = float(raw_input("Enter a number "))
    except:
        number = None
print "%d to the 3rd power is %d" % (number, thirdpower(number))
```

Comment: The edit doesn't seem to match what was trying to be done in the question. The function thirdpower was a separate function to be called from the main login. The use of the same variable - number - might confuse the issue, but I was going with the original code. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, having a break statement in your while loop is a bad practice(not to mention `while True`), you should always focus on 
having a condition that will quit itself

you can do something like this

```
user_input = input("enter a number")
while user_input == "" : #or other conditions you want to put
    print("error message")
    user_input = input("enter a number")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your number is going to be raw_input from the user, then you could assign what number is before entering the while loop, or have the parameter passed to the function handle that.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is this:

```
while True:
    try:
        number = int(input('Enter a number: '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter an integer.')

print('%d to the 3rd power is %d' % (number, thirdpower(number)))
```

In a `try` statement, if something goes wrong it looks for an `except` block. So in your case, when a user enters something that cannot be converted to an integer such as a non-number string or whitespace, it will fail and produce a `ValueError`. It will then look for the corresponding `except` block, and execute the statements nested within.

As it is in a `while` loop, this will keep happening until the input is found to be valid (by no exceptions occurring) and the `while` loop is broken, with `number` being the last entered value.

Comment: The guy is just learning how to define functions, so I don't think a try/except block is a good idea.

Comment: @Nope why not? Now that it is fully explained it is clearly the best way.

Comment: I said this on my answer's comments, but how would you do it without a try/except?

Comment: @daveydave400 with several unpythonic `if` statements, I suppose. This isn't about posting the most basic solution, it's about posting the best solution. Downvoter clearly hasn't got a clue what they are doing. Why do several `if` statements when you can handle all the invalid inputs in a `try:... except:...` structure?

Comment: I appreciate the answer Alex. Python doesn't seem to like my len function I gave. Is there anyway to use what I wrote instead of using the     try statement? I like the simplicity of your code, I just want to see if its possible using what I have.

Comment: @user3386440 Python doesn't like your len statement because you are asking for the length of a function. You should instead check for input validity with `if not my_input_value: raise Error`. However I can't completely help you as there are alot of logical problems in _your_ code. Look at some tutorials on while loops. I cannot just solve your entire program as it would no longer be relevant to the question. Also, if I have been beneficial to you, kindly accept my answer.

Comment: I also realized, you can't `len` an integer. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try breaking up the problem in to multiple parts, getting the value and calculating the "thirdpower".

You will also want to make sure to convert your user input into an integer.

```
while True:
    try:
        user_val = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print "You didn't enter a valid integer"
thirdpower(user_val)
```

If you want float values just change "int" to "float". You may also want to return the value from `thirdpower`:

```
def thirdpower(number):
    n = number**3
    print "%d to the 3rd power is %d" % (number, n)
    return n
```

Comment: Why would you suggest a try/except block for someone that is just learning how to declare functions?

Comment: Because it is the proper way to do something like this. You are trying to convert a value to something else. If it can't be converted you need to know that. Stop being a troll and -1'ing every answer that uses a try/except. It is the proper way and not too complicated.

Comment: @Nope, how would you do it without a try/except?